# Mesh uses too many draw calls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have some mesh, imported from blender(three.js exporter from utils folder), it has only 3 materials, but it uses 28 draw calls, why does this happen? As i thought it should use only 3 draw calls

[mesh image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq3L7.png)

Comment: I wouldn't be able to say for sure without inspecting the scene and associated objects. Materials can be shared between Meshes, so it's not beyond the realm of possibility that there are multiple meshes or draw groups referencing the same materials.

Comment: Probably has 28 different meshes. Using 1 material or 28, will still result in 28 draw calls.

Comment: @TheJim01
here is an example 
https://jsfiddle.net/9hye2yqn/

Comment: @pailhead
no, i have only 1 mesh, 1 geometry, 2 materials and for unknown reason 28 draw calls

Comment: Interesting. I was never able to wrap my head around the whole mesh->multiple material use case anyway. I'll follow this to see what the problem was.

Comment: @pailhead I'm not very skilled in three.js or blender, may be a reason is that it is chosen geometry type(instead of bufferGeometry) in exporter(as i read on github, its broken)?

Comment: The blender exporter is not maintained i think. It's very buggy. Best practice might be to use a different format for transfer, like glTF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In blender, go into edit mode.. select all your faces, then use the Mesh->Sort Elements->Material command to group the faces by material.. and then re-export.

You can sort by different criterion with that command. It can be really useful for doing an effect like having your object slowing build from the ground up for instance...

You can sort the elements along some direction, and then in three.js manipulate the draw groups on your mesh over time to render more and more faces.

hth

Comment: this seems like a good solution, there has to be a way to pre-format the data and this seems to be it thank you

Comment: this should ultimately be documented somewhere on three.js but they seem to be removing all the exporters

Answer (score 1):

When creating a **single** `Mesh` instance, and assigning it at an array of two `Material`s. Three.js does indeed create 28 draw calls.

It's due to this group system that `BufferGeometry` seems to use.

```
0:{start: 0, materialIndex: 0, count: 12}
1:{start: 12, materialIndex: 1, count: 12}
2:{start: 24, materialIndex: 0, count: 24}
3:{start: 48, materialIndex: 1, count: 12}
4:{start: 60, materialIndex: 0, count: 12}
...

27:{start: 378, materialIndex: 1, count: 6}
```

As to why, this would be a really good question to post on github. This is not how WebGL should work in general as it is extremely inefficient. The least amount of calls needed to render some geometry with two different shaders is two, not twenty eight.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure tbh. These indecis seem to be interwoven (mat1,mat2,mat1,mat2) you need to reach into this structure, extract all the 0 materials, all the 1 materials, re order them.

Comment: @pallhead, thanks a lot, i just parse geometry for faces and vertices and create separate geometry for every material

Comment: That might actually be an even better solution!

Comment: @pallhead
>this would be a really good question to post on github
sorry, but i hardly understand why this happened, and what i am doing, so I hardly can create a normal issue

Comment: It is not optimal to have so many draw calls, BUT, they are somewhat lighter weight draw calls, since they wont need to re-bind/recompute the object matrices for each call since they stay the same.

But it is definitely a potential lurking performance problem that is not obvious unless you're really looking for it.

See my answer below about sorting your faces by material in blender, below. :)